# rootFolder.ContentTypeOrder throws unexpected error for sandbox solution

Tags: development, list, document-library, content-type, sandbox-solution

I'm trying to add content types into a library list, in order to make "Visible on New" option ticked.

Firstly I enabled contenttypes in the library, then I want to do this:

```
SPFolder rootFolder = list.RootFolder;
IList<SPContentType> ctList = rootFolder.ContentTypeOrder;
rootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = ctList;
rootFolder.Update();
```

But this line `IList<SPContentType> ctList = rootFolder.ContentTypeOrder;` keeps throwing `unexpected error`:

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': 
Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute 
method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

I'm not sure if this error is related to the sandbox solution.

Related question: [Content Types not visible under New Button](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30703/content-types-not-visible-under-new-button)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's related to the sandbox, because you cannot use [SPFolder.ContentTypeOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.contenttypeorder%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [SPFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.uniquecontenttypeorder%28v=office.14%29.aspx) in sandbox :\

> Assembly:  Microsoft.SharePoint (in Microsoft.SharePoint.dll)
>
> Available in Sandboxed Solutions: No

**Edit:**

If it's just to order, the code posted as an answer by James in this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13649/content-type-ordering-or-making-it-default-ct) might work.

Comment: Thanks! However I'm not ordering... I just want to enable the CT on New button